# Problems with Codeblocks

Tags: 18.04, code-blocks

I installed Codeblocks 17.12-1 and it's not responding after building the file.
So I wanna try Codeblocks 16.01 from the terminal but it shows errors.

```
:~$ sudo apt install codeblocks
[sudo] password for salil: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
codeblocks : Depends: codeblocks-common (= 16.01+dfsg-2.1) but it is not 
going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
:~$
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f` and try again

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I tried that, doesn't work. Still shows the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the codeblocks-common.

```
sudo apt-get remove codeblocks-common
```

then

```
sudo apt install -f 
sudo apt-get update.
```

Now try to reinstall. It should work now.